# R & geom_histogram: bar positions for log plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am working on some analysis and want to insert a histogram. My current code is:

```
g <- ggplot(tg2, aes(x = n))
g <- g + geom_histogram(color = "white", fill = "steelblue", bins = 43)
g <- g + scale_x_continuous(trans = 'log10',
        breaks = trans_breaks('log10', function(x) 10^x),
        labels = trans_format('log10', math_format(10^.x)))
g <- g + scale_y_continuous(trans='log10',
        breaks = trans_breaks('log10', function(x) 10^x),
        labels = trans_format('log10', math_format(10^.x)))
g <- g + annotation_logticks()
g
```

The resulting plot is: [image: this histogram]

Is it possible (or even trivial) to get the individual bars to align with the log tick marks on the horizontal axis? I've searched, but come up empty.

What about the gray background? Is it possible to get the white grid to be on the same log scale?

Answer (score 0):

Several things. First, what made you choose `bins = 43`? Second, is providing the scale manually necessary? If the data is in the right format, you should not need it. If it isn't, first transform the data and then do it.

Third, gray background is from the default theme. There are [several options](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggtheme.html) but I like `minimal`. `minimal`, `linedraw` and `bw` have white grids.

(I'm generating 1000 random numbers for this example.)

```
v = tibble(var = rnorm(1000))
ggplot(v, aes(x = var)) +
   geom_histogram(bins = 20) +
   theme_minimal()
```

[image]

Comment: I picked `bins = 43` effectively by eye since I didn't want the usual 30 bins. I would like one bar for each unit on the log scale, but I don't know how to tell R to do that. I'm aware of many background options, but I've never seen one for log (or semi-log) scales.

Comment: Have you tried transforming your data prior to plotting?

Comment: No, I hadn't, but only because I don't see how it would affect anything. It's a simple log-log plot, but in some other cases, I only take the log of one axis.

Comment: Can you provide sample data? That'll help.

Comment: Each data set is pretty big (100s of MB), but the contents aren't important. The horizontal axis is a set of integers from 2 to some large number and the vertical axis is a number of counts.